# Laravel localization not showing text

Tags: php, laravel

I installed this plugin : https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization
It is for having a internationnal version of a website.

Everythink worked nice until there is a bug, I do not understand. I dont change anything but now, whenever I have the /fr /en /es etc... that indice it works, the translations has all disappear.

And I have now : /fr :

home.text-to-translate instead of the real text to translate...

I know I use composer dump autoload recently... I dont know anything else

How to debug please ?

edit : it works with php artisan serve but not on localhost

can you explain ?

Comment: can you explain what kind of bug do you have ? maybe screenshot ? or link ?

Comment: what version of laravel do you have ? does they compatible ? 

anyway you can debug with phpunit, here for example :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger.php